# Sub panel wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Should my feeder cable come up from the bottom of panel or can I run it over the top? Or will that cause too much of a bend? The wire come up from the attic floor about 8 inches behind where I need to mount. Also should I put wires in conduit? The panel will be in an unfinished attic in New York state.

The panel is a Square-D 24 space sub-panel.

[image]

[image: back of mount]

[image: cable]

[image: panel]

Comment: Title says sub panel, body says main service wire, which is it? A main service wire goes to a main panel, and a sub panel is feed by a feeder from a main panel (or another subpanel, eventually leading back to a main panel.)

Comment: Can you post the markings on the feeder cable please?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your panel. Many can be fed top or bottom as is more convenient - the documentation will say, but also you'll see embossed text repeated the other way up as a quick diagnostic. I would suggest using a panel that is correctly designed to have the main breaker placed top or bottom (by how the panel is mounted) and run the incoming wire directly to a main breaker on the bottom, rather than running the incoming wire at the bottom up and down.

Your incoming feeder cable appears to be 4-wires, not 3 as you described it, which is a **good thing** as you need all 4 wires for a sub-panel. You should protect the feeder cable from damage, but that can be done with appropriately placed plywood (*etcetera*) rather than requiring conduit. But conduit is also an acceptable method.

The picture of the panel does not show anything either supporting or contradicting "inverted" mounting (main on bottom.)

Answer (score 1):

### Subpanels work differently than main panels

It sounds like you have experience hooking up a 100A main panel and you are trying to apply that experience to a subpanel.   Can't do it, too many things are different.

A subpanel requires separate neutral and ground wire, so you have to use 4-wire e.g. SE-R (such as in your photo)... rather than 3-wire e.g. SE-U.

You must separate neutral and ground in the subpanel, which usually means you need to buy an accessory ground bar. You cannot put grounds on the neutral bar in a subpanel.

In subpanels, #2 is only good for 90A, not 100A.  That's no big deal, the 90A breaker is actually a bit cheaper.   You could use 1-1-1-3 for 100A, but most of the time, people just chose 100A as a nice round number; they don't actually *need* it and can do fine with 90A.

#6 aluminum, which I see in your photo, is good for 50 amps and needs a 50A supply breaker. That will still power a lot of stuff.  Nothing wrong with aluminum if the terminals are aluminum-rated (which panel and breaker terminals definitely are)... but it's important that every wire type have the terminals torqued to specification.*

3-wire cable is only allowed from the utility connection, through the meter and to the main breaker.  Since it is totally non-fused, it can dead short at up to 10,000 amps and nothing will prevent this.   As such, it is required to be *very* short and armored.  There is no way a main panel would be in an attic.  As such, this must be a subpanel.

---

* The difference is, when a copper wire fails due to improper torque, people say "It must be a poor connection" and they look at torque as a cause. When aluminum fails due to improper torque, they go "must be the aluminum wire, apparently it's not safe after all!" /facepalm. This is called "confirmation bias".

Comment: Yes this is will be a sub panel, I think the feed is actully 6-6-6-6/4 service entrance cable.

Comment: Then you should further edit your question to correct that, though we can at least see that it's 4-wire cable in the new pictures. For pictures, try to stay one blank line away (on both sides) from the code that's inserted to place the picture when editing.

Comment: @Steve well that's good. SER is the right stuff, and 6 AWG has different wire bending rules than the big stuff, it's hard to go too wrong.  Note that #6 aluminum is 50A wire and the feed breaker can't exceed 50A.

Comment: Ok so Ill just bend it up and come in from the bottom with no conduit. That will atleast elimanate a chafing point. Does derating apply to a sub panel? 50A feed breaker for 4-15A breakers?

Comment: @Steve The subpanel feeder must be large enough for **The Load To Be Served**, which is defined in NEC Article 220 as a "Load Calculation".  Generally 3 VA per square foot of the area served by lighting and general-use receptacles, plus 1500 VA per kitchen and laundry 20A receptacle circuit, plus the nameplate data of fastened-in-place appliances (125% of nameplate data for heaters, certain other loads and continuous loads)... minus a favorable fudge factor called out in Article 220.  TLDR: you're fine for four 15A circuits but you'll have to crunch the numbers before adding anything big.